# Monitors don't get signal after waking from sleep PC, only by shutting it down and booting it back up

Tags: windows-10, boot, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, reset

I'm having a weird issue in which my monitors only get a signal if I shut down the PC and boot it back up, every time I press the power button or choose to put the PC in sleep mode when it comes back to life the monitors won't get a signal.

I read that the problem may be caused by having dual monitors so I tried to just connect my main one on the DisplayPort port of the graphics card but this still occurs.

This didn't happen with my previous GFX card, I recently changed from an AMD card to a GeForce RTX3060, the card seems to be working fine and it's properly connected, I uninstalled the AMD drivers before installing the NVidia ones.

During the install I had a stupid issue so I popped out the motherboard battery and the pressed the RAM reset button but I've since then reconfigured my BIOS settings to what they were.

Does anyone have any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: I  used to get this sometimes, when coming back from sleep mode.  My diagnosis was that the system was busy.  I noted that firefox had been hogging up to much cpu.  It has nothing to do with multiple monitors.  It could be your driver.

Comment: Does this occur when using other types of cables (e.g. HDMI)?

Comment: Yes, I currently have two monitors, one connected to the DisplayPort and one on HDMI, I tried different DisplayPort ports and also connecting just the one monitor to DisplayPort or the other on HDMI and this keeps occurring.

Comment: Thank you @RohitGupta - I did notice that if I press Shift + Control + Windows Key + B I sometimes can wake up the monitors for some reason.